# wp_head() add a second title tag

Tags: wordpress

Here is my code from header

```
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo('charset'); ?>" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo('pingback_url'); ?>" />
<title><?php wp_title('|', true, 'right'); ?></title>
<?php wp_head(); ?>
....
```

I have no active plugins.
there are 2 filters for wp_head - none is used to displayed ' title ', 
also there is no other wp_title or ' title ' in the whole theme code.

Any ideas about how i can remove the second title?

Comment: make sure you do not have add_theme_support( 'title-tag' ); in the functions.php

Comment: Where is the second title appearing? Can you show the generated html?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a post I have recently done on WPSE

The two title tags can be explained as that you are using a theme that is written for Wordpress4.1 and actually is using 4.1. As from 4.1 you don't need to call [`wp_title()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_title) in the head any more, you can make use of new `title_tag` theme support tag which automatically adds the `wp_title()` tag in the header

The parent theme you are using are most probably already doing this. Look in your functions.php for this line of code

```
add_theme_support( 'title-tag' );
```

As a solution, copy the parent theme `header.php` to your child theme and simply remove the `wp_title()` function from the child theme `header.php`

Here is also a great function to keep in mind for backwards compatibility and is useful for parent theme developers: (*Taken from the codex*)

```
 if ( ! function_exists( '_wp_render_title_tag' ) ) {
    function theme_slug_render_title() 
    {
        ?>
        <title>
            <?php wp_title( '|', true, 'right' ); ?>
        </title>
        <?php
    }
    add_action( 'wp_head', 'theme_slug_render_title' );
}
```

Comment: Thank you - add_theme_support( 'title-tag' ); was the answer :)